# Why does the limit of $\frac{9}{(x+3)(x-3)}$ as x approaches 3 from the right...

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

The original problem was to find the limit of $(\frac{3}{x-3}-\frac{3x}{x^2-9})$ as x approaches 3 from the right. I used GCD and simplification to end up with the limit of $\frac{9}{(x+3)(x-3)}$ as x approaches 3 from the right.

I know that the answer is supposed to be infinity, but why? I graphed the function so I can tell that the limit will be infinity from a visual graph alone, but is there an algebraic way to deduce this too by just simply looking at it? If I plug in x = 3, the fraction would be 9/0 and that is an indeterminate.

Comment: $0/0$ is indeterminate, $9/0$ is not (both are undefined)

Answer (score 1):

It is true that plugging in $x=3$ is not defined, but the question wants to know how the ratio tends as $x$ gets closer and closer to $3$ from the right. So, to gain some intuition, use your calculator to find the value when $x = 3.001$ and $x = 3.0001$ and $x=3.00001$.. Do you see the trend? Now, how could you have guessed this without plugging into the calculator? For every $x$ to the right of $3$ (that is, every $x$ larger than $3$), the ratio is positive (the numerator is positive and both terms in the denominator will be positive). However, as $x$ gets closer to $3$, the denominator is getting closer and closer to $0$, and with a fixed non-zero numerator, the closer the denominator is to zero, the larger in magnitude the ratio will be.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you have seen the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition to prove that a finite limit exits.

How do you rigorously prove that the limit equals infinity, we tweak the definition slightly.

You will want to show that:

$\forall M>0, \exists 0 < \delta$ such that $0<(x-3)<\delta \implies f(x) > M$

So instead of sqeezing the limit inside some arbitrarily small $\epsilon.$  You are saying choose and abitrarily large $M,$ and I will show that no matter how large of an $M$ you choose, the function will break this boundary.

$\frac {9}{(x+3)(x-3)} > M$

let $\delta$ be no greater than 1

$0<(x-3)<\delta \implies 6<(x+3)<7$

$\frac {9}{(x+3)} > \frac 97$

$\delta = \max (1,\frac 9{7M})$

$0<(x-3)<\delta \implies \frac {9}{(x+3)(x-3)} > M$